# How to geofence logical Azure SQL Servers?

Tags: azure-sql-database, firewall

I have a logical Azure SQL Server (Paas), this server hosts dbs for an in-house desktop app for people in multiple countries. I want to be able to geofence access to the server only to those countries where I know my clients are.

Using the firewall rules on the server doesn't work because not all my clients have static IP addresses, so I need to be able to accept connections from any IP originating in those countries, which are far more than the 128-entries cap on Azure, even mixing database-level rules with server-level rules isn't enough because that only gives me 256 entries (not to mention the headache it would be to keep that updated).

So, how do I limit access to the server to only those specific countries where my clients are?

Comment: as logical servers are free in SQL Azure, you can just use multiple servers to isolate per country if you'd like.

Comment: For the sake of the exercise there's only one database in the server. The issue is that the amount of IP ranges that I need to allow is greater than the 128-entries cap on the server. Multiple servers wouldn't solve the issue here.

Comment: I think you can define multiple schemas. This can be logically isolated.